# SQL Query change row values

Tags: sql-server

Consider i have 2 employers(Google,Yahoo) and google is having 3 employee's and yahoo is 2 employee

My query should add

```
1000 to employee1 for google company
2000 to employee2 for google company
3000 to employee3 for google company

1000 to employee1 for Yahoo company
2000 to employee2 for Yahoo company
```

For each set of employees it should adding salary starting from 1000

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to calculate the new Salary:

```
SELECT Company, 
       Emp, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Emp) * 1000 + Salary As NewSalary
FROM YourTable
```

If you want to actually update the salary, one way is to use that query as a [`CTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;WITH CTE AS (    
SELECT Company, 
       Emp, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Emp) * 1000 + Salary As NewSalary
FROM YourTable
)

UPDATE T 
SET Salary = NewSalary
FROM YourTable T
INNER JOIN CTE C ON(T.Company = C.Company AND T.Emp = C.Emp)
```